# Convert __bridge CFType to support ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Could some one help me convert the below code to support ARC?

```
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DINPro-Medium" size:14];
CTFontRef ctBoldFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)boldFont.fontName, boldFont.pointSize, NULL);
CGColorRef cgColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x2b776d).CGColor;

NSNumber* underline = [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleSingle];
NSDictionary *ULSubattributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     CFBridgingRelease(ctBoldFont), (id)(id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                     cgColor, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,underline, (NSString*)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName, nil];
```

I am getting a crash on the last line saying,

```
*** -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x20ad4910
*** -[Not A Type class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x20ad4910
```

I hope this is a duplicate question. But I am stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Can you run NSZombies and determine what was over-released?

Comment: I think this lead to problem in your last line.. CFBridgingRelease(ctBoldFont)

Answer (score 3):

Here is some actual working code of mine that does something quite similar to yours:

```
 CTFontRef font2 =
     CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits (
         basefont, f, nil, kCTFontBoldTrait, kCTFontBoldTrait);
 NSDictionary* d2 =
     @{(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName: CFBridgingRelease(font2)};
 [mas addAttributes:d2 range:encRange];
```

Note that I do *not* release `font2`! `CFBridgingRelease` means "ARC, this object has been retained; *you* release it when the time comes." And ARC does. No leak, no zombie, no crash, no problem.

(On the other hand, `basefont`, which was created earlier with `CTFontCreateWithName` and was never handed over to ARC for control, must be released explicitly with `CFRelease`.)

Here is a whole lot more Core Text code from my book, showing ARC memory management throughout:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_core_text

And here is the section of my book about CFType memory management with ARC:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management_of_cftyperefs

Answer (score 2):

```
/* OK */UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DINPro-Medium" size:14];
assert(boldFont); // just be sure
/* OK */CTFontRef ctBoldFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)boldFont.fontName, boldFont.pointSize, NULL);
assert(boldFont); // just be sure

/* 1) CGColorRef cgColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x2b776d).CGColor; */
CGColorRef cgColor = CGColorCreateCopy( UIColorFromRGB(0x2b776d).CGColor );
assert(cgColor); // just to be sure

/* OK */NSNumber* underline = [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleSingle];

NSDictionary *ULSubattributes = @{ 
/* you don't own the kCT strings */(__bridge NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName : CFBridgingRelease(ctBoldFont),
/* ... */   (__bridge NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : CFBridgingRelease(cgColor),
/* ... */   (__bridge NSString *)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName : underline };
```

1) There is a bug in iOS pre-iOS6 where ARC will release the UIColor backing the CGColorRef while you are still using the CGColorRef. I know this since I created a rdar which was then reported as fixed in iOS 6.

PS: a nice blog by Mike Ash [here](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html)

EDIT: this code works fine in my iOS demo app (deploy set to 5.1 and 6 both) - see the log message. I made the dict an ivar.

```
{

    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    assert(boldFont); // just be sure
    CTFontRef ctBoldFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)boldFont.fontName, boldFont.pointSize, NULL);
    assert(boldFont); // just be sure

    CGColorRef cgColor = CGColorCreateCopy( [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8f green:0.8f blue:0.8f alpha:0.8f].CGColor );
    assert(cgColor);

    NSNumber* underline = [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleSingle];
    assert(underline);

    ULSubattributes = @{ 
        (__bridge NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName : CFBridgingRelease(ctBoldFont),
        (__bridge NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : CFBridgingRelease(cgColor),
        (__bridge NSString *)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName : underline };

    NSLog(@"ULSubattributes: %@", ULSubattributes);
}
```

> 2013-04-12 11:48:20.294 WebViewScrollTester[44147:c07]
>   ULSubattributes: {
>       CTForegroundColor = " [ (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 )";
>       NSFont = "CTFont \nCTFontDescriptor {type = mutable dict, count = 1,\nentries =>\n\t1 :
>   {contents = \"NSFontNameAttribute\"} =
>   {contents = \"Helvetica\"}\n}\n>";
>       NSUnderline = 1; }

EDIT2: I even added a dispatch_after to show nothing has gotten released by ARC:

```
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            NSLog(@"ULSubattributes: %@", ULSubattributes);
        } );
```

Comment: Thanks David, Its giving me the same error here: (__bridge NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : CFBridgingRelease(cgColor).